# Printing key values of multi level dictionary in python

Tags: python

I have following data:-

```
data={
    "a":{
        "b":{
            "c":1
            },
            "f":5
        },
    "d":"2",
    "e":"3",
    "g":{
        "h":{
            "j":"10"
            }
        }
    }
```

I tried and currently I have following code:-

```
def myprint(d):
    for k, v in d.iteritems():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print "{0}".format(k, v)
            myprint(v)
    else:
        print "{0} : {1}".format(k, v)

   myprint(data)
```

The above code prints following:-

```
a
b
c : 1
f : 5
e : 3
d : 2
g
h
j : 10
```

I wanted the output to be following:-

```
a__b__c = 1
a__f = 5
d = 2
e = 3
g__h__j = 10
```

Following is the IDE link: https://ideone.com/hWlYUM

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass along a prefix for recursive calls:

```
def print_nested(d, prefix=''):
    for k, v in d.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            print_nested(v, '{}{}_'.format(prefix, k))
        else:
            print '{}{} = {}'.format(prefix, k, v)
```

Demo:

```
>>> print_nested(data)
a_b_c = 1
a_f = 5
e = 3
d = 2
g_h_j = 10
```

Comment: thanks for the answer. I am a newbie to python. If you can please tell me more regarding the prefix used it would really help me :)

Comment: @HarkiratSaluja: there is nothing Python specific about what I did here. Recursive calls are passed the prefix built so far; so for the top-level values that are not dictionaries, there is no prefix (`''` is an empty string), but for the values under the `a` key, the prefix becomes `a_`. There is a `b` key in a nested dictionary, so the recursive call passes in `a_b_`, etc.